# How to get the sum of a user input in a for loop?

Tags: python-3.x, for-loop, input, sum

1. step: I will let the user write how many numbers he/she can write.
2. step: the user can write for example 2.
3. step: the user write 2 and 4.
4. step: the sum of step 3 have to be build (6).

Step 1 - 3 is clear, but can anyone help me how to build the sum in step 4?

x = int(input("How many numbers do you have?: "))

for i in range(x):

```
print(i+1,".number is")
y = int(input())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a sum variable that starts off as `0`.
Then in each iteration of the loop you just add `y` to `sum_`.

```py
sum_ = 0
for _ in range(x):
  y = int(input("> "))
  sum_ += y
print("Sum: ", sum_)
```

You should also handle the case of non numeric characters being entered ([catching the error](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions))

I used `sum_` instead of `sum` since `sum` is a builtin function (which you should not just overwrite).
Also, instead of `i` in the range loop, I discarded the index using an underscore (some IDE's would otherwise tell you that you are not using the variable)

Comment: Thank you for your answer and your detailed explanation, it have solved my problem. *THUMBS UP*

Comment: If so, I'd be glad if you could mark the answer as "Accepted Answer".
Glad I could help though :)